# Preloading styles with NextJS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

We are using NextJS and Ant-design for our site, and upon loading the pages, it gives a FOUC. How can I preload the styles before it loads the js? So we have a globals.css file and just to break the styles down each component has his own styles module file.

Here is /pages/_app.js if that's any help:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Head from "next/head";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";
import AppHeader from "../components/MainMenu/header";
import AppHeaderEN from "../components/MainMenu/MenuEN/headerEN";
import ScrollButton from "../components/ScrollToTopWidget/scrollToTopButton";
import CookiesEN from "../components/Cookies/cookiesEn";
import CookiesAF from "../components/Cookies/cookiesAf";
import Footer from "../components/MainFooter/Footer";
import FooterEN from "../components/MainFooter/FooterEN";

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const tagManagerArgs = {
        gtmId: "GTM-NV63HC6",
      };
      TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
        jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
}, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tidioScript = document.createElement("script");
    tidioScript.src = "//code.tidio.co/x6prkzftri0czsnncigtqpailkwuzx3o.js";
    tidioScript.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(tidioScript);

    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(tidioScript);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <div className="main">
      <Head>
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
              !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
              {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
              n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
              if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
              n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
              t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
              s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
              'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
              fbq('init', '205242273286619');
              fbq('track', 'PageView');
            `,
          }} />
      </Head>
       {router.pathname === "/en" ||
      router.pathname === "/en/" ||
      router.pathname === "/about-us" ||
      router.pathname === "/press-room" ||
      router.pathname === "/benefits" ||
      router.pathname === "/terms-and-conditions" ? (
        <AppHeaderEN />
      ) : (
        <AppHeader />
      )}

      <Component {...pageProps} />
      
      <ScrollButton />
      {router.pathname === "/en" ||
      router.pathname === "/en/" ||
      router.pathname === "/about-us" ||
      router.pathname === "/press-room" ||
      router.pathname === "/benefits" ||
      router.pathname === "/terms-and-conditions" ? (
        <CookiesEN />
      ) : (
        <CookiesAF />
      )}
      {router.pathname === "/en" ||
      router.pathname === "/en/" ||
      router.pathname === "/about-us" ||
      router.pathname === "/press-room" ||
      router.pathname === "/benefits" ||
      router.pathname === "/terms-and-conditions" ? (
        <FooterEN />
      ) : (
        <Footer />
      )}
      </div>
    </>
    
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

and here is /pages/_document.js :

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/brojure-site/image/upload/v1696333014/assets/logos/fav_afqres.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```